# Do template parameters need to be forward declared or does the type definition to be known

Tags: c++

Basically I have this code, but GCC complains that the vector cannot 
be constructed with an empty type. Has anybody encountered this problem 
before? I should mention that Vertex3D is only used through pointers in 
the file and so there should be no reason for the whole type to be 
known by the compiler. I dont know how templates behave in this 
respect..

```
//#include "cgVertex3D.hpp"                                                                                                                                                                                              
#include "cgDirection3D.hpp"

#include "cgHandedness.hpp"

class Vertex3D; // Forward declaration to avoid mutual header include

class Polygon3D {
  // Vertices constituting this polygon
  vector<Vertex3D*> *vertices = NULL;

  public:
    ...
```

Comment: Did you `include <vector>` and `using namespace std;` somehwere?

Comment: What exactly is the error that GCC produces?

Comment: A vector of **pointers** to something that simple as a 3d vertex sounds very much like Java. Why not just a `vector<Vertex3D> vertices`?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Christian I keep pointers to avoid duplication, Polygon-Vertex is a many-to-many relation in this case..

Comment: @MatthiasHueser Ah, I see. And what's the need for `vertices` to be a pointer?

Answer (score 7):

All standard containers require the type to be complete. Since you're creating a vector of pointers, that's not an issue (pointer type derived from an incomplete type can be used as a type argument there). The error in your code is `= NULL;` part (well, unless `std::vector` itself is unavailable, then you additionally have to include `<vector>`), which makes little sense anyway. You initialise data members in the constructor, not the class definition body. And you definitely don't need to have a pointer to the vector.

```
// note that you probably *shouldn't* use pointers here, but whatever
class Polygon3D {
    std::vector<Vertex3D*> vertices;
    Polygon3D();
    // ...
};

// ...

Polygon3D::Polygon3D() : vertices() {}
```